# Drag n' Drop of object to a new window outside of Stage

Tags: java, javafx, drag-and-drop

With [JavaFX](https://openjfx.io/), I have setup `DragEvent`'s handlers for cells in a `TreeView`, that make it so that the data they contain can be dragged into other components inside the application. **It would be really nice** to allow to use also to **drag a cell directly outside the `Stage`**, and create a new window, i.e. a new `Stage`, with the data related to that dragged cell.

However, `DragEvent`'s **are no longer received if the mouse exits** the `Stage`. I thought of creating a transparent stage that would fit the whole screen and that could handle drag events everywhere, and make it mouse transparent also, but that doesn't seem to work.

```
Pane root = new Pane();
root.setStyle("-fx-background-color: transparent");
Scene scene = new Scene(root, 1600, 1600);
scene.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);
root.prefWidthProperty().bind(scene.widthProperty());
root.prefHeightProperty().bind(scene.heightProperty());

// *** this won't work ***
root.setOnDragOver(event -> Log.d("Drag over"));

Stage stage = new Stage(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
stage.setScene(scene);
stage.show();
```

On the other hand, `MouseEvent`'s are still received by setting `onMouseDragged`. The downside is that I would have to have a custom drag handler that would act as an intermediate and take care of the data related to the drag, and of the state of the drag n' drop.

Does anyone know a better&quicker solution, or something that I am missing altogether?

---

For a minimal reproducible example:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.input.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;
import javafx.util.Callback;

import java.util.LinkedList;

public class DragCellOutsideStage extends Application {

    public static final DataFormat LIST_DATA_FORMAT = new DataFormat("A nice format");
    public static final String CONTAINER_DEFAULT_STYLE = "-fx-border-color: indigo;\n" +
                                                    "    -fx-border-style: dotted;\n" +
                                                    "    -fx-background-color: #d1d1d1;" +
                                                    "    -fx-border-width: 3px;";
    public static final String CONTAINER_HIGHLIGHT_STYLE = "-fx-border-color: orange;\n" +
                                                        "    -fx-border-width: 5px;\n" +
                                                        "    -fx-border-style: solid;" +
                                                        "     -fx-background-color: gold";

    private Label dragLabel;



    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        // show transparent stage first
        Pane transparentRoot = new Pane();
        transparentRoot.setStyle("-fx-background-color: transparent");
        Scene transparentScene = new Scene(transparentRoot, 1600, 1600);
        transparentScene.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        transparentRoot.prefWidthProperty().bind(transparentScene.widthProperty());
        transparentRoot.prefHeightProperty().bind(transparentScene.heightProperty());

        // *** this won't work ***
        transparentRoot.setOnDragOver(event -> System.out.println("Drag over"));

        Stage transparentStage = new Stage(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
        transparentStage.setScene(transparentScene);
        transparentStage.show();


        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();

        initUI(root);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }


    private void initUI (BorderPane root) {
        ListView<String> listView = new ListView<>();
        listView.setPrefWidth(300);
        listView.setPrefHeight(400);
        listView.setCellFactory(new CellFactory());

        LinkedList<String> items = new LinkedList<>();
        items.add("Eat crunchies for breakfast");
        items.add("Feed the pigeons");
        items.add("Remember to breath");
        items.add("Stare at the clouds");
        items.add("Call grandma and ask her about health problems");

        listView.getItems().addAll(items);

        Label label = new Label("Things I have to do today:");
        label.setStyle("-fx-font-size: 14px");
        label.setPadding(new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5));
        VBox vBox = new VBox(label, listView);

        BorderPane dragContainer = new BorderPane();
        dragContainer.setPrefHeight(420);
        dragContainer.setPrefWidth(420);
        dragContainer.setStyle(CONTAINER_DEFAULT_STYLE);

        dragLabel = new Label("Drag things here! You won't regret it!");
        dragLabel.setStyle("-fx-font-size: 20px; -fx-font-weight: bold; -fx-text-fill: indigo;");
        dragContainer.setCenter(dragLabel);

        setupDragListener(dragContainer);

        root.setPadding(new Insets(15, 15, 15, 15));
        root.setLeft(vBox);
        root.setRight(dragContainer);
    }


    private void setupDragListener (Pane container) {
        container.setOnDragOver(new EventHandler<DragEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(DragEvent event) {
                Object content = event.getDragboard().getContent(LIST_DATA_FORMAT);

                if (!(content instanceof String)) return;

                event.acceptTransferModes(TransferMode.ANY);
            }
        });

        container.setOnDragDropped(new EventHandler<DragEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(DragEvent event) {
                String content = (String) event.getDragboard().getContent(LIST_DATA_FORMAT);
                dragLabel.setText(content);
            }
        });

        container.setOnDragEntered(new EventHandler<DragEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(DragEvent event) {
                container.setStyle(CONTAINER_HIGHLIGHT_STYLE);
            }
        });

        container.setOnDragExited(new EventHandler<DragEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(DragEvent event) {
                container.setStyle(CONTAINER_DEFAULT_STYLE);
            }
        });

        container.setOnDragDone(new EventHandler<DragEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(DragEvent event) {
                container.setStyle(CONTAINER_DEFAULT_STYLE);
            }
        });
    }


    class CellFactory implements Callback<ListView<String>, ListCell<String>> {

        @Override
        public ListCell<String> call(ListView<String> listview) {
            final ListCell<String> cell = new ListCell<>() {
                public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
                    super.updateItem(item,  empty);
                    if (empty) {
                        setText(null);
                    } else {
                        setText(item);
                    }
                }
            };
            cell.setOnDragDetected((MouseEvent event) -> dragDetected(event, cell));

            return cell;
        }


        private void dragDetected(MouseEvent event, ListCell<String> cell) {
            if (cell == null) return;

            Dragboard db = cell.startDragAndDrop(TransferMode.ANY);

            ClipboardContent content = new ClipboardContent();
            content.put(LIST_DATA_FORMAT, cell.getText());
            db.setContent(content);
            db.setDragView(cell.snapshot(null, null));
            event.consume();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: hmm ... see what you are after, interesting - need to go feed the pigeons <g>

Comment: @kleopatra I will be feeding my beloved pigeons soon but I want to resolve this matter first

Comment: was talking about my hungry pigeons :) Or in other words: faintly remember that I have seen a solution to a similar problem, but can't find it right now. sry.

Comment: @kleopatra thank you anyway, only knowing that there is possibly a solution reassures me that I will see my pigeons soon.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203984/discussion-between-slaw-and-alessandro-roaro).

Answer (score 0):

Solution based on transparent window.

```java
    import javafx.application.Application;
    import javafx.geometry.Rectangle2D;
    import javafx.scene.Scene;
    import javafx.scene.control.Label;
    import javafx.scene.input.ClipboardContent;
    import javafx.scene.input.Dragboard;
    import javafx.scene.input.TransferMode;
    import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
    import javafx.stage.Screen;
    import javafx.stage.Stage;
    import javafx.stage.StageStyle;

    public class DragAndDropApplicaton extends Application {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            launch(args);
        }

        @Override
        public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
            StackPane dropStackPane = new StackPane();
            dropStackPane.setStyle("-fx-background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.01);");
            dropStackPane.setOnDragOver(event -> {
                if (event.getDragboard().hasString()) {
                    event.acceptTransferModes(TransferMode.COPY_OR_MOVE);
                }
                event.consume();
            });

            dropStackPane.setOnDragDropped(event -> {
                Stage newStage = new Stage();
                Scene newScene = new Scene(new StackPane(new Label("New stage")), 400, 400);
                newStage.setScene(newScene);
                newStage.show();

                event.setDropCompleted(true);
                event.consume();
            });

            Scene dropScene = new Scene(dropStackPane);
            dropScene.setFill(null);
            Stage dropStage = new Stage();
            dropStage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
            dropStage.setScene(dropScene);

            Rectangle2D visualBounds = Screen.getPrimary().getVisualBounds();
            dropStage.setX(visualBounds.getMinX());
            dropStage.setY(visualBounds.getMinY());
            dropStage.setWidth(visualBounds.getWidth());
            dropStage.setHeight(visualBounds.getHeight());
            dropStage.show();

            Label label = new Label("Drag me!");
            label.setOnDragDetected(event -> {
                Dragboard dragboard = label.startDragAndDrop(TransferMode.ANY);
                ClipboardContent clipboardContent = new ClipboardContent();
                clipboardContent.putString("label-drag");
                dragboard.setContent(clipboardContent);
                event.consume();
            });

            label.setStyle("-fx-background-color: red;");
            StackPane stackPane = new StackPane(label);

            Scene scene = new Scene(stackPane, 400, 400);
            stage.setScene(scene);
            stage.show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: It works, that is, it handles the drop. But! I can't click anything under the transparent stage

Comment: I've added second solution. This one is not the best because of necessity of keeping transparent stage just below current stage.

Answer (score 0):

Solution without transparent stage

```java
    import javafx.application.Application;
    import javafx.geometry.BoundingBox;
    import javafx.geometry.Point2D;
    import javafx.scene.Scene;
    import javafx.scene.control.Label;
    import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
    import javafx.stage.Stage;

    public class DragAndDropApp2 extends Application {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            launch(args);
        }

        @Override
        public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

            Label label = new Label("Drag me!");
            label.setStyle("-fx-background-color: red;");

            StackPane stackPane = new StackPane(label);
            Scene scene = new Scene(stackPane, 400, 400);
            stage.setScene(scene);
            stage.show();

            label.setOnMouseReleased(event -> {
                BoundingBox bounds = new BoundingBox(stage.getX(), stage.getY(), stage.getWidth(), stage.getHeight());
                if (!bounds.contains(new Point2D(event.getScreenX(), event.getScreenY()))) {
                    Scene newScene = new Scene(new StackPane(new Label("New window")), 400., 400.);
                    Stage newStage = new Stage();
                    newStage.setScene(newScene);
                    newStage.setX(event.getScreenX());
                    newStage.setY(event.getScreenY());
                    newStage.show();
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: This would definitely work, but if you take a look at the example I posted in the question I need to also handle DragEvents. Or to use a different system completely that uses MouseEvents (simple drag and drop gestures) but that also supports data transfer

Comment: You can write your own data transfer logic.